# Use of LockableFileWriter class?

Tags: java, file, file-io, io

I'm new to Java and my project led me to dive straight into `apache.commons.io` library, I cannot understand the purpose of `LockableFileWriter class`.
Any specific usage example would help.

Comment: you mean `LockableFileWriter`  in apache commons?

Comment: @akhil_mittal ... yes? That *is* what the question says...

Comment: This is not how SO works. Take a look at the [JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/index.html) formulate a question with some code to show your effort and then ask the questions.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31154200/can-lockablefilewriter-class-in-apache-commons-library-be-used-to-perform-an-exc) do you mean this? @npinti

Comment: That is an improvement, but you just threw in some code and expect the community to give you an answer. Did you try to run the code yourself, and create some scenarios where the code might fail?

Answer (score 0):

As specified in apache doc:

> It is FileWriter that will create and honor lock files to allow simple
>   cross thread file lock handling.  If Writer attributes are
>   unspecified, the default behavior is to overwrite (rather than to
>   append), and to use the value of the system property `java.io.tmpdir`
>   for the lock file directory

Also check source for more.